# Calculate differences of a list using slots

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I want to calculate the differences between the numbers of a list. One way to do that is using 'Differences'.

For example:

> ```
> L = {1, 3, 6, 9};
> Differences[L]
> ```

this gives: {2, 3, 3}

My question is: can I get the same result if I use 'Map'and 'Slots'. I tried:

> Map[{#1 - #2} &, L]

This gives a error.
Who has a suggestion to solve this question.

Comment: Have you seen `MovingMap`? (I’m away from my computer, so I can’t check whether it may or may not work.)

Comment: Also see `BlockMap`.

Comment: if you're asking simply about `Map`, the answer is no, not like that: the function `f` in `Map[f, list]` is only ever presented with a single argument. To use `Map` sort of like that, you would have to modify `list` to have elements which are pairs of consecutive elements, perhaps via a particular use of `Partition`, then package a two-slot function into a single-slot one via `Apply`. Ultimately, though, `f` would still only ever see a single argument. But if you're simply looking for a way to do this in general, the solutions mentioned above are best! (Also usable is `ListCorrelate`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {1, 3, 6, 9};
```

Using slots with `Map` doesn't seem to be possible, but one can use them with `Apply` in more than one way:

**1.**

Using `BlockMap`

```
BlockMap[Apply[#2 - #1 &], a, 2, 1]
```

{2, 3, 3}

**2.**

Using `Partition`

```
#2 - #1 & @@@ Partition[a, 2, 1]
```

{2, 3, 3}

Using `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
MapApply[#2 - #1 &] @ Partition[a, 2, 1]
```

{2, 3, 3}

**3.**

Using `SequenceCases`

Without slots

```
SequenceCases[a, {a_, b_} :> b - a, Overlaps -> True]
```

{2, 3, 3}

With slots

```
SequenceCases[a, x : {_, _} :> (#2 - #1 & @@ x), Overlaps -> True]
```

{2, 3, 3}

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {1, 3, 6, 9};
```

Using `Partition` and `Differences`:

```
Splice@*Differences @@@ Outer[List, Partition[a, 2, 1], 1]

(*{2, 3, 3}*)
```

Or using `MovingMap`:

```
MovingMap[Splice@*Differences, a, 1]

(*{2, 3, 3}*)
```

Or using `Table`:

```
Table[#2 - #1 & @@ {#[[i]], #[[i + 1]]}, {i, Length@# - 1}] &@a

(*{2, 3, 3}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or `RotateLeft`.

```
L = {1, 3, 6, 9};
diff = Most[RotateLeft@# - #] &;
diff@L
```

> `{2, 3, 3}`

Answer (score 1):

```
(L // Rest) - (L // Most)
```

or

```
MapThread[Subtract,  {(L // Rest) , (L // Most)}]
```

or

```
Map[#[[1]] - #[[2]]&,  Transpose[{(L // Rest) , (L // Most)}]]
```

See, we use Map :)

Answer (score 1):

**Using `FoldPairList`:**

```
L = {1, 3, 6, 9};
FoldPairList[{#2 - #1, #2} &, L]
```

---

*Result:*

> {2, 3, 3}